# Build a heap using scan in parallel

Tags: tree, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I read on NVIDIA's website that one can build a tree in parallel using CUDA and scan operation. I was wondering if there are any documents that explain how one can build a heap in parallel using the scan operation. Any documents that contain the code for this will also be great. I have some values on the GPU memory out of which I need to return the top k values. I was thinking building a heap in Parallel and returning top k results would be a good idea.

Alternatively, if there are no such documents, I was wondering if there are any documents that explain how one can build a tree in parallel using scan.

Answer (score 1):

Sean Baxter discusses order statistics here:

http://www.moderngpu.com/select/mgpuselect.html

although his function implements selection of the k'th element, not computation of the top k elements.

His Web site also features extensive coverage of Scan.